# Dynamic lambda wrapped with try catch

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda

I want to filter an `IEnumerable<ModuleItem>` by an Where calls defined by the user (so the expression is given by a String object)

So far I am able to create my filters with DynamicLinq with this code

```
Expression<Func<ModuleItem, bool>> expr = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<ModuleItem, bool>(value, null);
```

The problem is that the overall filtering will fail if the evaluation fails for an item in the collection. So I would like to catch the exception within the lambda and return false instead to filter out the failing item.

I tried wrapping the expression with `TryExpression.TryCatch(...)` but I cannot get back an `Expression<Func<ModuleItem, bool>>`

How can I wrap my dynamic expression and get back an `Expression<Func<ModuleItem, bool>>` object to use as the Where argument ?

Comment: You have an `IEnumerable`, not an `IQueryable`, so why are you dealing with expressions, instead of just delegates, in the first place?

Comment: You need a block with a return statement.

Comment: I don't really care whether it is expression or blocks. My constraints here is to get an expression as a String and feed it to a IEnumerable.Where call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tries I got this working.
The solution was to use the trycatch to wrap the expression's body and not the expression itself then create the resulting lambda using the expression parameters.

Otherwise I got something like (not sure there) a `Func<ModulelItem, bool, bool>`

So the final code is

```
Expression<Func<ModuleItem, bool>> expr = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<ModuleItem, bool>(value, null);
Expression triedExpr = TryExpression.TryCatch(expr.Body, Expression.Catch(typeof(Exception), Expression.Constant(false)));
Func<ModuleItem, bool> whereDelegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<ModuleItem, bool>>(triedExpr, expr.Parameters).Compile();
```

Comment: Need to remove surplus parenthesis on last line of code example